# htaccess redirect to domain without subdomain with no hard coding

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i need to redirect all requests of form http://static.name.ext/first/second/etc
to http://www.name.ext if first segment is not "assets"

so keep requests of form http://static.name.ext/assets/etc redirect others

i tried with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L]
```

but %{HTTP_HOST} returns the subdomain and i don't want that

Comment: _“but %{HTTP_HOST} returns the subdomain and i don't want that”_ – well then in your RewriteCond _capture_ what comes after `static.`, and reference it in your RewriteRule instead of `%{HTTP_HOST}` …

Comment: thanks i'm a beginer at htaccess, i had no idea i can capture in the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/ [R=301,L]
```